# Capistrano cap deploy fails on ubuntu 10.10. Installed Ruby with RVM

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, capistrano, webby

I installed ruby 1.9.2 via RVM as well as the webby and capistrano gems.  Webby doesn't work with 1.9.2 so I backed up to ruby 1.8.7 via RVM set it to default and webby is better.

When running *cap deploy* on this previously functioning site (for someone else) I get the following:

> ryan@ruby1:~/projects/cincinnati-agile-conference$
>   cap deploy
>   /home/ryan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in
>   `gem_original_require': no such file
>   to load -- railsless-deploy
>   (LoadError)
>                   from /home/ryan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in`
>   require'
>                   from /home/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/capistrano-2.5.19/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:152:in
>   `require'
>                   from Capfile:5:in`load'
>                   from /home/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/capistrano-2.5.19/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:172:in
>   `load_from_file'
>                   from /home/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/capistrano-2.5.19/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:89:in`
>   load'
>                   from /home/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/capistrano-2.5.19/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in
>   `load'
>                   from /home/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/capistrano-2.5.19/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in`
>   each'
>                   from /home/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/capistrano-2.5.19/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in
>   `load'
>                   from /home/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/capistrano-2.5.19/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:65:in`
>   load_recipes'
>                   from /home/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/capistrano-2.5.19/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:65:in
>   `each'
>                   from /home/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/capistrano-2.5.19/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:65:in`
>   load_recipes'
>                   from /home/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/capistrano-2.5.19/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:31:in
>   `execute!'
>                   from /home/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/capistrano-2.5.19/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:14:in`
>   execute'
>                   from /home/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/capistrano-2.5.19/bin/cap:4
>                   from /home/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/bin/cap:19:in
>   `load'
>                   from /home/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/bin/cap:19

Google-fu leads me to suggestions not to use ruby packages, but I used RVM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you fell back to 1.8.7, did you install the railsless-deploy gem?

Comment: That was it!  Thanks.  Didn't realize I needed to do that manually.  Newb+10

Comment: RVM has some great tools for managing this. Look into its suport for default gems. Also, was railsless-deploy in your Gemfile? If you're using bundler then a 'bundle install' will install all dependencies in the rails project's Gemfile, including the entire dependency tree. It's worth familiarizing yourself with it if you'll be working in rails regularly.

Comment: the site doesn' have a Gemfile... I've used bundler before on another app that was already setup and that was *very* nice.  I'll do that and update the site.  Thanks again!